# Mongoose In ArrayElemAt Issue In Aggregate

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

**temporaryshifts is equal to**

```
[{_id:123,
arr:[{_id:123321,name:"Bluh Bluh",date:"bluh bluh"}] 
}]
```

so i want to access temporaryshifts[0].arr[0]
but i dont know how to access

```
$project:{
shiftArr:{$arrayElemAt:['$temporaryshifts',0]}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make use of the let operators to make use of two `$arrayElemAt` Operators.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "temporaryshifts": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "masterKey": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$temporaryshifts",
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          "in": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$$masterKey.arr",
              0
            ]
          }
        },  
      }
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AMH91J7hd8c)

Answer (score 0):

To Understand Properly i Am taking this example and suppose that this our data

```
`
[
      {
        _id: 123,
        arr: [
          {
            _id: 123321,
            name: "Bluh Bluh",
            date: "bluh bluh"
          },
          {
            _id: 1233219,
            name: "Bluh Bluh2",
            date: "bluh bluh2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        _id: 1234,
        arr: [
          {
            _id: 1233214,
            name: "Bluh Bluh4",
            date: "bluh bluh4"
          }
        ]
      },
      
    ]

`
```

Can get temporaryshifts[0].arr[0] with this query

```
   db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        "$match": {
          "_id": 123
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          shiftArr: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$arr",
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

You need to match at the first time to get the document and rest of thing **arrayElementAt** can manage.